# Can we use rbac permissions without the authProvider system?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

We are using react-admin and we would like to setup permissions system access to our resources. We see that we can add permissions in `getPermissions` in the `authProvider` but we are using our own auth system today.

Is it possible to add permissions without add others auth functions (checkAuth, login, logout, checkError) ? When using Typescript, both of them are required.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible in react-admin - all those methods are required. If you don't need them, they can simply return a resolved Promise.

But I'm puzzled: If your app has different roles/permissions but no authentication, what prevents a user from impersonating another user with different permissions?

In other words, in all authentication systems, to my knowledge, authentication is necessary to allow authorization (=permissions).

Comment: Thank you for your response !

We have an auth system (using auth0) and we received permissions from there. I just want to do something like inject permissions in react-admin system (like rbac) to manage permissions without adding lots of custom code.

I tried to add empty functions like `login: () => Promise.resolve()` but it make the login button to be display in the header.
So for you I have to use resolved promise and hide the login button as work around ?

Comment: yes, in react-admin, permissions are only available if you use authentication